# OptionParser does not take ampersand '&'

Tags: python-2.7, optionparser

I have problem using OptionParser in python.
When I give '&' as one of the character in input it will discard the '&' and characters next to it are treated as separate command.
Here is the sample code for test.py:

```
  from optparse import OptionParser
  cmdParser = OptionParser()
  cmdParse.add_option("-n", "--USER", help="User Name")
  cmdParse.add_option("-p", "--PASSWORD", help="Password")
  (options, args) = cmdparser.parse_args()
  uname = options.USER
  pwd = options.PASSWORD
```

When I run it with command: **python test.py -n sample -p 123&45**
password it reads only 123 and sayd 45 is not recognized as interna and external command error. All other special symbols works fine except '&'.
It works fine if I give **-p "123&45"**. But I don't want to specify string explicitly.
Is it a limitation with OptionParser?
Any help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `python test.py -n sample -p '123&45'` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with `optparse` - your program never sees anything beyond the ampersand because that is interpreted by your shell. "&" is used in many shells to start a command in the background. So your command line is being interpreted as "run `python test.py -n sample -p 123` in the background and then run the command `45`", explaining your error. The solution is to quote your option, as you have already found out. This is a limitation of the shell and can not be fixed by anything you do in Python as the program never sees the whole option.

PS: You [shouldn't be using `optparse` anymore](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) - rather use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Comment: If it is a limitation of the shell, then how its going to work with argparse. The shell should behave same way with argpase also right?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. `argparse` will not solve the problem with the "&". I put in the PS part because `optparse` is deprecated as shown in the help and you should be using `argparse` instead for new projects.